# Inject javascript code into string

Tags: javascript

In a mobile app of mine, I have a line of js code like `document.getElementById('ID_HERE')`
I want to replace `ID_HERE` with some javascript code. The only part I can communicate to the app from my server is `ID_HERE`.

I am not able to remove the single quotes until I release another update of the mobile app, unfortunately, so I'd like this as a temporary solution if possible.

Can this be accomplished (and how)?

Comment: maybe you can do a string replace

Comment: By "some javascript code" do you mean actual code, or a different selector?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You have a line of JS in the app, you want to change that line? How are you going to run the code that changes the JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirements exactly, but perhaps you can do a single-quote injection? That is, replace `ID_HERE` with

```
'+(2*3)+'
```

so this shows up as `document.getElementById(''+(2*3)+'')`.

If this is your situation, then replace `2*3` with any javascript code.

---

Another option: Replace `ID_HERE` with:

```
'+(function() { alert("hi!"); return 'ID_HERE'; })()+'
```

resulting in

```
document.getElementById(''+(function() { alert("hi!"); return 'ID_HERE'; })()+'')
```

Then replace `alert` with any code, and it still gets the `ID_HERE` element (or anything else you want to change it to.)

Comment: To build upon this. Try body'); alert('injected');//  Shouldn't it alert injected if it was successful?

Comment: I'm not sure why I overlooked this as an option. Thank you.